# Drupal custom Fullcalendar breaks jQuery version > 1.8

Tags: javascript

I have a project where I have created a pretty extensive (custom) fullcalendar implementation.

I am using fullcalendar 2.6 (the latest version at this point).

All is working like a charm untill i change the jQuery version (via jquery_update) to anything that is higher than 1.8...
Then the fullcalendar just dissapears completely (the div is empty)

No errors in the webdeveloper console (chrome), nothing!

I have tried to narrow down the fullcalendar js implementation to the bare minimum (just a title, prev & next buttons) but even that does not work.

Since i want to implement bootstrap into the project, I need to increase the jQuery version...

I have been googling around for this but can't seem to find a clear answer for this.

Anyone?

All suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have located the problem, sharing to whom it might concern.

Apparently there was a conflict between the contrib admin_menu rc4 version and jQuery, causing the fullcalendar to fail.

After upgrading the admin_menu to rc5, (latest release), all was fine.